# Google Deployment Manager template using environment variables

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a template called dev.yaml that looks like this:

```
imports:
- path: generate_config.py

resources:
- name: application_vm
  type: generate_config.py
  properties:
    zone: europe-west1-d
    project: cpb1234567
```

Note that I am hardcoding the zone and project. I want those to come from these environment variables.

```
CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west1-d
GCP_PROJ_ID=cpb1234567
```

The generate_config.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

COMPUTE_URL_BASE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/'

def generate_config(context):

  resources = [{
      'name': context.env['name'],
      'type': 'compute.v1.instance',
      'properties': {
          'zone': context.properties['zone'],
          'machineType': ''.join([COMPUTE_URL_BASE, 
                                  'projects/', 
                                  context.properties['project'],
                                  '/zones/',
                                  context.properties['zone'],
                                  '/machineTypes/n1-standard-1']),
          'disks': [{
              'deviceName': 'boot',
              'type': 'PERSISTENT',
              'boot': True,
              'autoDelete': True,
              'initializeParams': {
                  'sourceImage': ''.join([COMPUTE_URL_BASE, 
                                          'projects/',
                                          context.properties['project'],
                                          '/global/images/jre-10gb-debian-jessie'])
              }
          }],
          'networkInterfaces': [{
              'network': ''.join([COMPUTE_URL_BASE, 
                                  'projects/',
                                  context.properties['project'],
                                  '/global/networks/default']),
              'accessConfigs': [{
                  'name': 'External NAT',
                  'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT'
              }]
          }]
      }
  }]
  return {'resources': resources}
```

I am getting the zone and project from the properties, so that works.

BUT, how do I get the zone and project from the environment variables?

I can't seem to do this in the Python template:

```
import os
...
os.environ['GCP_PROJ_ID']
```

As the import fails.

In the YAML, it is not clear what syntax would work.

Many thanks

Nathan

Comment: It's also impossible to use 'os' library within the Python template, so programming is quite limited to the [allowed ones](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/import-python-libraries).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not an answer as such, more information is here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/Md7rCo1ZMJY

Comment: Thank you for this - they could just have called environment variables "deployment manager environment variables" or something similar..? Very confusing when other parts of GCP allows you to set and retrieve environment variables.